# How to use a jQuery variable in a selector

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to highlight the table cell that is in row, col.

```
var $tr = $('tr:eq(' + row + ')');
$($tr:nth-child(col)).addClass('highlight');
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML and value of `row` and `col` please?

Comment: Syntax error near ':' in line 2 -- is that supposed to be pseudocode?

Comment: I was trying to keep the source code to only a minimum so as not to distract from the question.  Maybe from now on I'll go ahead an post the entire page.  After all, Copy/Paste is a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var $tr = $('tr:eq(' + row + ')');
$tr.find(':nth-child(' + col + ')').addClass('highlight');
```

Using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/). See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/R7T3B/).

Alternatively, if you don't need a reference to the `$tr`, you can do it all via one selector:

```
$('tr:eq(' + row + ') :nth-child(' + col + ')').addClass('highlight');
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/R7T3B/1/))

---

As for your question

> How to use a jQuery variable in a selector

The result of (all) jQuery traversal / selector methods is of type [`jQuery`](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#jQuery). This makes it possible to do advanced chaining. Also, it is on this type that the jQuery methods is defined. This means that you need to perform filtering etc. *on* the resulting object. Thus, the following is invalid (`:` is not a JavaScript operator, `nth-child()` is (probably) not defined as a JavaScript function):

```
$($tr:nth-child(1)).addClass('highlight');
```

But can be rewritten as:

```
$tr.find(':nth-child(1)').addClass('highlight');
```

Here we're applying the selector `:nth-child(1)` on the `jQuery` object assigned to `$tr`. This object can hold a reference to any number of DOM elements, even zero!

Comment: nice, forgot about using jsfiddle :)

Comment: jensgram, this was a very complete and well thought out answer.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

i'm guessing something like this?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.highlight{
    color:red;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var row = 1;
    var col = 2;
    $("tr:nth-child(" + row + ") > td:nth-child(" + col + ")").addClass('highlight');

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="1">hello</td>
        <td id="1">hello2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="2">world</td>
        <td id="2">world2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this page, http://jsfiddle.net/, useful for trying out codes and even more awesome when attached to so threads so other people can try and modify the code :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to escape the first set of double quotes -- leave the single
quotes there.

```
var row = "billy";  
var $tr = $("tr:eq('" + row + "')");
$($tr:nth-child(col)).addClass('highlight');
```